# How does Windows 11 bootrec /scanos find Windows installations?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, uefi, windows-11

**How does Windows 11, "bootrec /scanos" identify the Windows 11 OS?** and
**How can the: "Total Identified Windows installations: 0" be fixed?**

**Problem:**
When running bootrec /scanos from Windows Recovery Environment no Windows installations are found, even when clearly one is there.

**Scenario:** A Windows 11 Pro Hyper-V VM, UEFI-GPT boot.

**Already tried:**
I have tried various proposed solutions including:

- Disk Cleanup
- export & re-import the VM,
- `Chkdisk /r /f`
- `sfc /scannow`
- `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

Much of the information I found is out of date and relates to BIOS-MBR and any steps to try fix appear not to work, including:

- `bootrec /FixBoot`
- `bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-UK /s z: /f: UEFI /v` *(where z: was the drive letter mapped to the EFI FAT32 partition)*
- `bootrec /rebuildbcd`

Thanks